# Permissions Error When Viewing Records Even with an Organization Level Read Privilege

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a security role assigned to a user. This security role has organization level READ access to almost all of the entities in CRM. When the user opens the contact entity, he is able to view the list of all contacts in the system. However, when the user opens a specific contact record, he gets an insufficient permissions error and is unable to view the form.

Checked that the customizations tab also have read permission on the following entities
1. Attribute Map
2. Entity
3. Entity Map
4. Field
5. System Form
6. View

I expect to be able to view the details of the contact. Permissions error is displayed instead.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot? Download log button enabled?

Comment: It is recommended to copy existing Security role and customize it. There are many hidden permissions that you need on many OOTB entity records...

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of some lookup entity in the contact form, for which user does not have the read privilege.

Verify each lookup entity & security role privilege.

Comment: Those user has read access to those lookup entities as well. Which entities should be given an access level besides the read access on the contact entity?

Comment: @user2050472 let’s say you have account lookup in contact form, check if account read privilege is missing. do you have any field level security? Just doing guess work.

Comment: No field security.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft this is the minimum set of permissions for contact/account access:

**Core Records**
Account: Read(Organization)
Contact: Read(Organization)
User Entity UI Settings: Create(User), Read(User), Write(User)

**Business Management:**
User Settings: Read(User)

**Customization:**
Customizations: Read(Organization)
System Form: Read(Organization)
View: Read(Organization)
Web Resource: Read(Organization)

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f52f26e5-8684-4fd7-a89f-4dd34972c0ed/minimum-security-permissions-to-view-accounts-amp-contacts?forum=crm